# When to use Kendall's tau b vs c?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have gone through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient but am still a little confused.

I have two columns of data I wanted to compare using Kendall's tau. One is actual deciles (1-10) and the other is predicted (1-10). My data is not square, it is rectangular, but the data is on the same scale. Does this mean I should use tau b? Or could I use c? The reason is that compare to a baseline value one performs better and one performs worse. I am using scipy's `kendalltau`.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it isn't on-topic for stack overflow. I suggest [statistics.se]